# How to find inverse mapping, if its invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse-function

i know that to show invertibility, i have to prove that its either bijective or matrix is upper triangular. But i don't understand how to head start on this. Can anyone please help me with that?[image]

Comment: It would be better if you would remove the image and instead state your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, try to use proper capitalization. This would help improve the readability if your post.

Comment: In general, try to show your work/your thoughts about the question. You said you don't understand how to start, see [this]("no clue" questions? - Mathematics Meta - Stack Exchange
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com › ...
) for the communities view in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to show invertibility, i have to prove that its either bijective or matrix is upper triangular.

Not all upper triangular matrices are invertible, so no.  You could do something with matrices, and that would be a good second exercise, but you can really just directly see the answer to this.

Let’s get it of the way that, as sums of linear operators, these operators are linear.

The first one is obviously not invertible: $x^2$ is in the kernel. (That was the first thing I tried.)

Considering that the second one maps $a+bx +cx^2$ to $(a+b+c,b+2c,2c)$, it is clear that the kernel is zero and so the map is invertible.

The inverse is rather easy to see by inspection: solving for $a,b,c$ in $(X,Y,Z)=(a+b+c,b+2c,2c)$ yields $(X,Y,Z)\mapsto (X-Y+Z/2)+(Y-Z)x+(Z/2)x^2$ as the inverse image.